# Wasserstein / Earth Mover Distance - explain the KR Duality form

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces

In the WGAN paper, the Kantorovich-Rubinstein duality form of the distance is given as:

$$W(\mathbb P_r, \mathbb P_{\theta}) = \sup_{||f||_L \le 1} \mathbb E_{x\sim \mathbb P_r}[f(x)] - \mathbb E_{x\sim \mathbb P_{\theta}}[f(x)]
$$

On wikipedia, on the other hand, it is given as:

[image]

Can someone explain how the WGAN version is equivalent to the Wiki one?

Comment: If $X\sim \mu$, then $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\int f\,d\mu$. This is essentially the definition of the distribution of a random variable.

Comment: @MaoWao shouldn't $E[f(x)] = \int f(x) p(x) dx$ ?

Comment: That only works if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous. For example, you won't find such a function $p$ if $X$ is deterministic.